# timeout spark workers tasks for bottleneck of oracle

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, cassandra

We have a system programing on spark and oracle DB. the bottleneck of my system is when workers would insert or update in DB, there are timeout error on some executors of workers. We have 6 worker which has 64G RAM and 8 cores. number of execution is equal to cores of worker and each executor run a task. oracle DB has 16 cores and 96G RAM. We think our spark cluster is bigger than DB system and insert or update for big data(each executor maybe insert or update 7G data simultaneously) is it true?
the other issue is that the distributed DB like Cassandra is a solution for this bottleneck?

Comment: You may need to tune Spark parameters (JDBC settings).  Change of database to Cassandra is significant change, and will require to change (or rewrite) all applications that consume data

Comment: have you run any performance queries to see what exactly the problem is?

Comment: I search about JDBC settings and found it for java but we programing in python. I think it could not available for python.is it true? Alex Ott.

Comment: unfortunately we did not direct access DB to study performance queries in detail :-(. but  executors read a batch from DB as much as memory capacity. So the data that refer to DB was huge because of number of executors (48). we have error of executors which said timeout on DB connections. OldProgrammer